# How to sync local MySQL database to Amazon RDS database?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, mysql-workbench

I am setting up a connection between **MySQL Workbench** and **Amazon AWS RDS** MySQL database. How can I sync the two databases?

The operation (Inserting, deleting and updating) directly happens to cloud (AWS RDS) database instead of storing first on the local database which is further sync to cloud. Because it is taking much time in storing procedure directly to the cloud.

I expect all operations happen ***first in a local database*** which then ***syncs to the cloud database***.

Comment: Your question is not clear. 1. MySQL Workbench is not a database, it's just a client. 2. So you have a local database and AWS RDS, you want to sync it? - have a look at - https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/65351/sync-two-mysql-databases-in-two-different-locations

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in using the AWS Database Migration Service, which should be able to meet all of your requirements including remote replication of your local database. (https://aws.amazon.com/dms/)